# How to process text withing brackets starting from inner brackets first

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a text with has nested parenthesis in it. I need to process the test from inner most parenthesis, apply some logic and then move 1 level up and repeat the processing. Is there any way we can access the string within each of the paranthesis in the order of their depth.

E.g :

```
( xy ( ef (ab) (cd) gh ) ,  ( mn  (op) (qr), st ) z )
```

Expected procesing should first process :

```
(ab) (cd) (op) (qr)
```

Next:

```
( ef (ab) (cd) gh ) and ( mn  (op) (qr), st )
```

and lastly

```
( xy ( ef (ab) (cd) gh ) ,  ( mn  (op) (qr), st ) z )
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Please post your code.

Comment: The regex you need is `r'\([^()]*\)'`. Use a loop with `re.search` to check if the regex matches, and process however you like with `re.sub`

Comment: This always gets the first occurrence of the match.